# Replacing remote repository with a local one

Tags: git, github

How can I replace a remote repository with my local one? I force push it to my local repository but, the old files that are not part of my current one stay, similarly named ones are replaced in the remote repo however.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to replace all files in your remote repo from a new local repo?